# Force child element visible outside an overflow:hidden parent

Tags: html, css

Only solution I found was to put a `position: fixed` on element I want to fully see. Any other options? (I dont want to 'cool-image' fixed). Help or hint would be awesome. Also, if anyone can explain solution - that would be even better

Fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLjmw7xh/)

HTML

```
<div class="img-cont">
  <div id="slider">
    <ul>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://www.sportspearl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/football-150x150.png" >
        <div class="cool-image"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-cont{
    height: 270px;
    position: relative;
}
#slider {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 440px;
    height: 200px;
}
#slider ul{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#slider ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 440px;
    height: 270px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
}
div.cool-image{
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid #EEEEEE;
    width: 650px;
    height: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Basketball.png/170px-Basketball.png);
    margin-left: -40px; /* Just to product situation */

    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your desired outcome a bit more?

Comment: @JeffHechler div.cool-image is partly hidden because of parent value overflow: hidden. Is there a way to change some css rules, so, that div.cool-image is fully shown. (You can inspect and see, that cool-image is shown only as big as the parent is. I want cool-image to be fully shown even tho parent is overflow: hidden)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. The child element is only capable of changing within the parents region when the position is not set to `fixed` or `absolute`.

If you don't want to make the child fixed, you could try `position:absolute;` and set the parent to `position: relative;`

Like this...

```
.slide img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
}
```

Or you could try to only hide the overflow on 1 direction. Like `overflow-y:hidden;` Or `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: I your suggestions, but didn't succeed. Can you edit my fiddle? I'm interested in first approach.

Comment: Thanks for the one-direction overflow `overflow-x-y` That was it!